# List overwrites every entry when updated

Tags: c#, list

I have a static public List of type BoxPair which I'm trying to write stuff to, but it changes every record every time I add a new entry into it. I'm hoping someone can see what's going wrong here, as it's driving me slightly insane. The full addition code is below:

```
public static List<BoxPair> CreateBoxPair (int iBoxCount)
{
    SetTopBox primary;
    SetTopBox backup;

    for (int i = 0; i < iBoxCount; i++)
    {
        primary = new SetTopBox();
        backup = new SetTopBox();

        primary.IBoxNumber = i;             
        primary.SDeviceName = "Box" + (i + 1).ToString("00");
        primary.Role = Box.ROLE_PRIMARY;

        backup.IBoxNumber = i;
        backup.SDeviceName = "Box" + (i + 1).ToString("00");
        backup.Role = Role.ROLE_BACKUP;

        lstBoxes.Add(new BoxPair(primary, Role));
        lstBoxes.Add(new BoxPair(backup, Role));

        foreach (BoxPair p in lstBoxes)
        {
            Declarations.BOXES.Add(p);
        }             
    }                        

    return lstBoxes;
}
```

I know it's going to be something basic, but from what I can see, I'm always using a new primary/backup box, so nothing should conflict. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

P.S. Every post I make, SO removes the first word, so I have to type it twice. Any ideas as to why that happens?

EDIT: As all the approaches listed below have given the same result, I'm guessing that this is a problem that cannot be solved. Therefore, I'm returning to the drawing board to try and approach this differently. Thanks for all the help, anyways, chaps :)

Comment: for removing first word, u would be using hi or greet msg. so SO removes that i guess

Comment: `changes every record every time I add a new entry into it.` - by "each time" you mean each loop cycle or each `CreateBoxPair()` method call? and which list overwrites: `lstBoxes` or ` Declarations.BOXES`?

Comment: What calls this function? Can you show us that? Can you show examples of what's happening and what you expect?

Comment: @sll I only fire the method once. Every time through the loop, each entry that exists is updated, and the new one is entered.

Comment: Is `Declarations.BOXES` somehow related to `lstBoxes` programatically? What is Type of both `lstBoxes` and  `Declarations.BOXES`, some standard or self-made ?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I call this in the initializer. I expect to have a list of 32 boxes, with names Box01 to Box16 for both primary and backup roles. Instead I get 32 boxes named Box16 on both roles.

Comment: @sll No, it's just a global list. All I do is copy the final lstBoxes into it. Both are of type BoxPair

Comment: @Skulmuk That's your issue. If you're adding them to Declarations.BOXES in the loop THEN adding lstBoxes into that later on.. you'll have duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments my best bet on code that works is as follows:

```
public static List<BoxPair> CreateBoxPair (int iBoxCount)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < iBoxCount; i++)
    {
        var primary = new SetTopBox();
        var backup = new SetTopBox();

        primary.IBoxNumber = i;             
        primary.SDeviceName = "Box" + (i + 1).ToString("00");
        primary.Role = Box.ROLE_PRIMARY;

        backup.IBoxNumber = i;
        backup.SDeviceName = "Box" + (i + 1).ToString("00");
        backup.Role = Role.ROLE_BACKUP;

        var primaryPair = new BoxPair(primary, Role);
        var backupPair = new BoxPair(backup, Role);

        lstBoxes.Add(primaryPair);
        lstBoxes.Add(backupPair);

        Declarations.BOXES.Add(primaryPair);
        Declarations.BOXES.Add(backupPair);
    }                        

    return lstBoxes;
}
```

I think there are two issues in the original code:

- `primary` and `backup` being declared outside the loop.
- The `foreach` loop inside the loop adding the entries to the other collection multiple times.

Comment: Exactly! but still have to check with the q what the logic of foreach inside a for..

Comment: Looks like line with `foreach` could be removed

Comment: I've taken your advice and removed the foreach loop, but it still does the same thing. I'm doing the following now:

    Declarations.SET_TOP_BOXES.Add(lstBoxes[i]);

Do you think there's anything wrong there?

Comment: @Skulmuk: It is hard to give any further help. Your problem description is somewhat vague and hard to correlate to the code snippet you have provided.

Comment: As promising as that sounded, it didn't work. I've moved the `foreach` loop outside of the `for` loop, but it still updates the entire list.

Comment: @Skulmuk: See my answer for details of how to update your code, but Martin is the first who found the problem

Comment: Apologies, Martin. I know it's a bit of a vague request. I just ran the code you suggested, and checked each entry in `lstBoxes`. Every entry's name was "Box16", as opposed to box 1 being "Box1" and box 7 being "Box07".

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
lstBoxes.Add(new BoxPair(primary, Role));
lstBoxes.Add(new BoxPair(backup, Role));

foreach (BoxPair p in lstBoxes)
{
    Declarations.BOXES.Add(p);
}
```

By this:

```
var p1 = new BoxPair(primary, Role);
var p2 = new BoxPair(backup, Role);
lstBoxes.Add(p1);
lstBoxes.Add(p2);
Declarations.BOXES.Add(p1);
Declarations.BOXES.Add(p2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, @sll, but even that has failed. I think I'm going to have to try and work out a different approach to this problem, but thanks for all the help regardless.

Answer (score 0):

I think your just missing the lstBoxes var declaration, `List<BoxPair> lstBoxes = new List<BoxPair>;.`

```
public static List<BoxPair> CreateBoxPair (int iBoxCount)
{
    SetTopBox primary;
    SetTopBox backup;

    List<BoxPair> lstBoxes = new List<BoxPair>();

    for (int i = 0; i < iBoxCount; i++)
    {
        primary = new SetTopBox();
        backup = new SetTopBox();

        primary.IBoxNumber = i;             
        primary.SDeviceName = "Box" + (i + 1).ToString("00");
        primary.Role = Box.ROLE_PRIMARY;

        backup.IBoxNumber = i;
        backup.SDeviceName = "Box" + (i + 1).ToString("00");
        backup.Role = Role.ROLE_BACKUP;

        lstBoxes.Add(new BoxPair(primary, Role));
        lstBoxes.Add(new BoxPair(backup, Role));

        foreach (BoxPair p in lstBoxes)
        {
            Declarations.BOXES.Add(p);
        }             
    }                        

    return lstBoxes;
}
```

And if the lstBoxes is a public var that dont need to be in the function do not return it:

```
public static Void CreateBoxPair (int iBoxCount)
    {
        SetTopBox primary;
        SetTopBox backup;

        for (int i = 0; i < iBoxCount; i++)
        {
            primary = new SetTopBox();
            backup = new SetTopBox();

            primary.IBoxNumber = i;             
            primary.SDeviceName = "Box" + (i + 1).ToString("00");
            primary.Role = Box.ROLE_PRIMARY;

            backup.IBoxNumber = i;
            backup.SDeviceName = "Box" + (i + 1).ToString("00");
            backup.Role = Role.ROLE_BACKUP;

            lstBoxes.Add(new BoxPair(primary, Role));
            lstBoxes.Add(new BoxPair(backup, Role));

            foreach (BoxPair p in lstBoxes)
            {
                Declarations.BOXES.Add(p);
            }             
        }                        
    }
```

Comment: Tried both of those, but to no avail.